# Wordcount example on yarn in Hortonworks failing

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I have Hortonworks Sandbox with Hadoop 2.2.0 and I installed Apache-spark technical preview on the sandbox.

Though I am able to run a spark Java example in local mode, but I am unable to run the Java example in yarn-client mode.

Here are the steps I used for execution:

1. In the Eclipse IDE I created a Java project and under src director made a file JavaWordCount and the code was taken from sample example which comes with Apache spark.
2. Then I created the jar using Eclipse->export ->as a jar and had that jar file in my local system.
3. Then on the terminal I went to spark home directory and gave the following command:

   ```
   [train@sandbox spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041]$ b**in/spark-submit --class JavaWordCount --master yarn-client  --num-executors 1 --driver-memory 512m  --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1    /home/train/Desktop/sparkwc3.jar /README.md /out1
   ```

   where my file is on the hdfs.
4. I get the following error:

   ```
   15/02/28 11:04:02 ERROR cluster.YarnClientClusterScheduler: Lost executor 2 on sandbox.hortonworks.com: remote Akka client disassociated
   15/02/28 11:04:02 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Re-queueing tasks for 2 from TaskSet 0.0
   15/02/28 11:04:02 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, sandbox.hortonworks.com): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 lost)
   15/02/28 11:04:02 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
   15/02/28 11:04:02 INFO cluster.YarnClientClusterScheduler: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
   15/02/28 11:04:02 ERROR cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Asked to remove non-existent executor 2
   15/02/28 11:04:02 WARN remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@sandbox.hortonworks.com:34111] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
   15/02/28 11:04:02 INFO cluster.YarnClientClusterScheduler: Cancelling stage 0
   15/02/28 11:04:02 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at JavaWordCount.java:68, took 20.451136 s
   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, sandbox.hortonworks.com): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 lost)
   Driver stacktrace:
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:696)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
   at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor.aroundReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1375)
   at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
   at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
   at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
   at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
   [train@sandbox spark-1.2.0.2.2.0.0-82-bin-2.6.0.2.2.0.0-2041]$
   ```

Comment: Wondeful stracktrace... don't we all love such stacktraces? Too many layers of frameworks... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Probably the executor crashed. This page on the Spark website, http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html discusses how to view the various logs to hopefully find the issue. You might also experiment with the invocation flags and properties discussed, too.

For example, what happens if you omit the `--driver-memory 512m  --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1` flags?

Finally, does the path for the input exist in HDFS and do you have read permissions? Do you have write permissions for `/` so you can create `/out1`? (These shouldn't cause this error, however...)

Comment: Thanks @Dean .The permissions on HDFS are fine.When I run without arguments this is the error i get: 
 `15/02/28 22:34:03 WARN cluster.YarnClientClusterScheduler: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient memory

Comment: You might surf the Cloudera forums, since they support Spark. I don't work with YARN enough to have any more suggestions to offer.